# In symmetrical airfoils is the stall angle the same for negative AOAs as for positive ones?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, stall, angle-of-attack

In symmetrical airfoils is the stall angle the same for negative Gs as for positive ones? Let say the stall angle is 17 degrees AOA. Is it the same if you push the nose down?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/19247/33692)? I think it already answers your question. If not, feel free to clarify what is missing...

Comment: Now I seen your post.

Comment: As Bob Hoover famously said, an airplane only cares about airspeed to fly. Whether it is upside down or not don't means anything for the flight characteristics. For a symmetrical airfoil what is the difference between - 1000N of lift and +1000N of lift? You just reverse the succion-pressure side and voilà you have the same situation and thus the same behavior.